# jQuery if target.text() ==, do something

Tags: jquery

I've problem with a little function, I just want to let it toggle text on click, but there is a little problem, this text could be a little dynamic.
To be more clear, I will show two states of the text:

1. "Expand all 18"
2. "Hide all"

As you can see in the first example there is a numeric value, which could be dynamic.
I think regular expressions is a bit too heavy to understand and use here, so is it possible for jQuery look through text with following construction:

```
if(e.text() == 'Expand*'){//do something}
```

Or is it not possible and I need to do it with regular expressions?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akn2g/

Comment: what if you use `:contains()` ? http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do:

```
var txt = $(this).text();
if(txt.indexOf('Expand') == 0){
  //do something
}
```

full code:

```
$('.texted').on('click',function(){
    console.log('clicked');

    if($(this).text().indexOf('Expand') == 0){
        $(this).text('Hide all');
        return 0;
    }        
    if($(this).text().indexOf('Hide') == 0){
        $(this).text('Expand all');
        return 0;
    }
});
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akn2g/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are determined to use regular expressions, you would do this:

```
if (/Expand/.test(e.text())){
  e.text('Hide all');
}
else {
  e.text('Expand all ' + numItems); // numItems being the length og the list children.
}
```